# display discount box -prestashop

Tags: php, web, prestashop

In my prestashop app,I have added discount for special products via Admin panel
`Catalog->discount->Cart rules`
This discount is showing when item is on checkout.

but i want to  show that discount on top of the item.how can i check 'product has special discount' and display discount percentage or amount like below image?

i have tried this in tpl file

```
{if $product.has_discount}
{if $product.discount_type === 'amount'}
 <span class="p_deduction">- {$product.discount_amount}</span>
{/if}
{/if}
```

but this code work when i add discount for all products.

[Product discount](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sm3PQ.png)

Comment: Have you tried anything? Look at the DB, you'll find what you're looking for.

Comment: yes i have found some code.but it's apply when discout is for all products.i have eddited my post